# syntax error in php 5.3 for namespace

Tags: php, syntax

How i can fix this syntax error in php 5.3.28 ?

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ',' or ';'
>   in /home/......

```
protected $callback = DOMAIN.FOL_DIR.'/index/payment_back' ;
```

It work true at php 7 .

thanks

Answer (score 0):

PHP 5.3 doesn't support [constant scalar expressions](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/const_scalar_exprs). You need PHP 5.6 or newer for that.

Comment: there are not any method for this state ? dosn't important how .

Comment: Set `$this->callback` in the constructor instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use at lease PHP 5.6 to execute scalar expression. So please upgrade your PHP version and try.

Thanks...

Comment: Thank.but its just on 1 line surce need !!